# prove if $Z \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ has zero-content and $U \subset Z$, then $U$ has zero-content

Tags: analysis

I have to prove if $Z \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ has zero-content and $U \subset Z$, then $U$ has zero-content.

The definition of zero-content that my textbook states is this.

A set $Z \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is said to have zero-content if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite collection of rectangles $R_i$ such that

- $Z \subset \bigcup_i R_i.$
- The sum of areas of $R_i$ is less than $\epsilon > 0.$

What I tried is following.

Let $Z \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ has zero-content and $U \subset Z$. Since $Z$ has zero-content, there is finite collection of rectangles $R_i$ such that the above condition hold. Since $U \subset Z$, $U \subset \bigcup_i R_i$, and the sum of the areas of the rectangles is less than some positive $\epsilon$, $U$ has zero-content.

My textbook just skips a lot of proves by saying that they are easy, and I am having trouble checking if my proof is valid. Is my proof ok??

Comment: Looks OK to me. You could also assume that if $U$ didn't have zero-content, nor does $Z$.

Comment: What I was worrying about my proof was that I did not mention anything about second condition. It is that I just stated $U \subset \bigcup_i R_i$ and did not prove second condition for $U$. Is it ok just state $U$ is contained in the union of rectangles since we know the sum of areas of $R_i$ is less than $\epsilon$??

Comment: yes. the 'area' of $R_i$ is $\lt\epsilon$ so because $U$ is contained in $\cup R_i$ the 'area' of $u$ is also $\lt\epsilon$

Comment: $U\subset Z\subset R_i$, and the $\epsilon$ condition is carried through.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!!